# How to dynamically obtain app version without using context

Tags: android

I want to instantiate Retrofit in the periphery of the application, in classes that implement interfaces that require SOME networking library to do the API calls.

I want to add the App Version as a custom header to all my Retrofit requests, which can be done at Retrofit instantiation time.

I have no access to Context there and I want to be able to somehow obtain the app version dynamically (without hardcoding it each time) without the need for Context.

Or maybe I SHOULD pass the context to the networking library of choice anyway?

I only know this one way to get app version, using Context:

```
 private static String getAppVersion(Context context) {
        String appVersion = "";
        try {
            if (context != null) {
                PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                if (pInfo != null) {
                    appVersion = pInfo.versionName;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return appVersion;
    } // End of getAppVersion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Gradle/Android Studio you can get it statically with

```
int verCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String verName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Comment: How about on runtime?

Comment: @Dr.jacky The way it is explained in the question. But you need Context for that one.